# Vim errorformat <Nul> characters

Tags: vim, errorformat

The errors produced by `ghc-mod` are on a single line, where each line may potentially contain the `<Nul>` character, rendered as `\@` by vim. I'd like to parse this for quickfix, but can't see how this might work with `errorformat`: the `<Nul>` character seems to truncate `%m` as if it were a new line, but using multiline syntax doesn't seem to be working to catch this case.

Is there a way to make `errorformat` parse `<Nul>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A program that carelessly outputs null characters in a Unix environment is just *begging* for trouble.

No, for all I see Vim cannot handle null characters when parsing output with `'errorformat'`. (It is possible to add NULs to the errorformat string by prefixing them with `CTRL-V`, i.e. `^V^@`, but this is useless.)

The work-around for output that isn't suited for Vim's errorformat is to add a filter to the `'makeprg'` program and then use `:make` to populate the quickfix list:

```
:set makeprg=ghc-mod\ lint\ %\ \\\|\ tr\ -d\ '\\0'
:make
```

This hint can be found at the very end of [`:h error-file-format`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#error-file-format).

A much better solution is to simply not bother and use the popular [***ghcmod***](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4473) plugin that does this and much more.

Comment: I agree entirely: it's not a great idea to spit out nulls. The ghcmod plugin is good, but I'm trying to get this to work with syntastic instead.